# Non-stacking ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

There is probably a better way to do this, but here goes: I have a user control for each step of a user workflow process. I am using Microsoft Prism and dependency injection. I have an ItemsControl that is binded to a List. Anytime the user does an action that requires the next "step", I add the user control to this list, which the ItemsControl binds to.

Of course the user controls stack on top of eachother from top to bottom. What I want is to have the last one drawn be drawn ON TOP OF every other one. That way when the user is done with this step and hits "OK", I just remove the user control, and the previous step is automatically displayed.

Comment: sounds like you need a custom style for a `TabControl` instead of putting a bunch of UserControls on top of one another. Too many unused stuff in the Visual Tree will make your application needlessly slower and heavier in terms of RAM usage.

Comment: Speed isn't really an issue. There will be at most 3 "levels" of depth to this design, then when they are done all the controls are removed. I didn't want to have to do something complex like a custom contrl as it seemed like there should be a simpler way to do it:(

Comment: As as I said above, you don't need any custom controls. a `TabControl` will suffice. and it's a much more adequate solution to your problem.

Comment: Did you try adding the controls as children to a grid control?

Comment: I will try this, thanks. I've never written a custom style before so that would be more I'd have to do/learn, which I was trying to avoid if there was a simpler solution, but I will check that out also. Thanks.

Comment: Garry - Grid doesn't have an Items,Children, or ItemSource. I needed to be able to bind in xaml to a list in my ViewModel, so I don't know if that is an option, or I am missing something.

Comment: And HighCore-So you are saying to just add new tabs of content and make that the active tab, hiding the tabs of course, then when I am done, I just remove it and it will display the content of the last tab? That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

I created a tab control, as per HighCore's idea.

```
 <TabControl Name="MIPTabs" ItemsSource="{Binding UCList}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=Height}"  Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=Width}">
```

Each item in UCList is a UserControl, and its content gets automatically added to each new tab. I then hide the tabs with:

```
 <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
 </TabControl.Resources>
```

Then I use the following code so that each time a tab is added, it will set the selected tab equal to the newest tab:

```
 public MIP(IMIPVM viewModel) : this()
    {                

        this.DataContext = viewModel;


        var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, typeof(TabControl));
        if (dpd != null)
        {
            dpd.AddValueChanged(MIPTabs, UpdateTabs);


        }
    }


    private void UpdateTabs(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MIPTabs.ItemsSource);
        view.CollectionChanged += (o, f) =>
        {
            //This makes it so the last item ADDED is always the tab that is being displayed 
            MIPTabs.SelectedIndex = MIPTabs.Items.Count-1;
        };

    }
```